# How to create users in oracle when register an account on web

Tags: sql, oracle, web

My team have some problems with my database system assignment:

--- My team have already made a website, and we have register page in that clients must enter their information (include ID and password) to create an account

--- When clients finish register account step, my team must create an account from the ID and password that clients entered in Oracle (I mean after clients creating their account on our register page, we must synchronize it into our database in Oracle)

We have difficult at step "create an account from the ID and password that clients entered in Oracle"

Thanks you for reading my question

Comment: Do you want to create an Oracle user for the client once it is registered on your web site?

Comment: Yup!!! After clients registered an account from our website, we must create the same in database of Oracle, but I don't know how to code it in oracle :((

Answer (score 0):

Well, the common practice for such a situation is to save the customer's ID and Password in some table and then check if the customer with the entered ID and Password does exist in the table on each login.

However, if your need is to create an Oracle User, you can use the procedure like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_user(p_id VARCHAR2, p_password VARCHAR2) AS
   v_sql VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   v_sql:='CREATE USER '||p_id||' IDENTIFIED BY '||p_password;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
```

An additional thing you should pay attention is the privileges that should be given to that user. For example, in order to be able to connect to database with his user, he should have a CREATE SESSION privilege. After defining the list of necessary privileges, you can add their grants to the procedure.